# angular http post - trigger jenkins build with parameters

Tags: angular, http, jenkins, post, jenkins-api

using below typescript function to trigger a jenkins build -

```
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type':  'application/json',
   'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
   })
  };
triggerJenkinsJob(productname:string):Observable<any>{
   console.log("service called")
   var url = "http://jenkinsbox:30000/job/demo/buildWithParameters?project_name=demo"
   return this.http.post(url,this.httpOptions)
   .pipe(map(function(item){
     console.log(item)
   }))
 }
```

with the above code, nothing is executing on the jenkins box. I have tried running the below URL on the browser, which is working perfectly.

> http://jenkinsbox:30000/job/demo/buildWithParameters?project_name=demo

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why `triggerJenkinsJob('demo').subscribe()` does not as intended, you should read logs in your browser's console.

The first problem should be CORS. You may have a second problem with CSRF protection if there is one with Jenkins

Comment: I have installed CORS Support plugin and added the origin,headers over there. fyi, I have already consuming the /api/json. get request is already working. CSRF protection - I have also tried passing Jenkins-Crumb with headers as well.

Comment: What is the status / error of the POST request in the browser's developer tool console / network?